# 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' sending photo to telegram bot

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote below code for sending a photo to my bot, but in my stream, I have two exceptions for read and write and my photo was not send.

I think maybe the reason was this error, but I couldn't fix it:

> `stream.ReadTimeout` threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open("a.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    var fileToSend = new FileToSend("a.jpg", stream);
    Task.Run(() => bot.SendPhotoAsync(u.Message.Chat.Id, fileToSend).ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this exception is probably that you `Dispose` the `stream` immediatly after starting the task.

The `using` statement calls `Dispose` on the `stream` instance when execution leaves this block. You can either remove this `using` statement or - if your method already is `async` - you may simply `await` the call to `SendPhotoAsync()`. There is no reason to use another thread with `Task.Run()`:

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open("a.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    var fileToSend = new FileToSend("a.jpg", stream);
    await bot.SendPhotoAsync(u.Message.Chat.Id, fileToSend).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The state-machine created by the compiler for this `await` call takes care that the `finally` block of the `using` statement (where `stream.Dispose()` will be called) is executed only after the `Task` returned by `SendPhotoAsync` has completed.