# How do I solve this error in Stream.ReadTimeOut error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an exception in the following code:

```
(System.IO.MemoryStream) Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fcr.FileContents);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

I wrapped it in a Try/Catch & the exception is thrown on the second line: Message = "Parameter is not valid."

I checked the contents of the variable `stream`. This is where the error is. Expanding the contents of `stream`, I find:

```
Read.TimeOut: 'stream.Read.TimeOut'threw an exception of type 
'System.InvalidOperationException'
Write.TimeOut: 'stream.Write.TimeOut' thew an exception of type 
'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why wasn't the first error picked up in the Try/Catch?
2. How do I solve it?

   ```
   using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fcr.FileContents))
           {
           System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
   ```

Continues to crash in here with Parameter is not valid. 
The object stream still has read & write TimeOut messages.

Comment: where do you get the error? in which of the two lines? whats the exact error msg? btw you should use a using using a memory stream

Comment: The exception occurs in the second line of code shown here. The TimeOut errors were only shown when I hover over stream, in the first line of code.

Comment: What is `fcr`, an image? What kind?

Comment: fcr is a png image file

Comment: neither are null. the image exists

Comment: Maybe the stream is being disposed first.  Like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069026/stream-readtimeout-threw-an-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexceptio/43069192).  However, I don't see a using in your code.  It's probably related to something like this at least.

Comment: Putting the statement inside a using statement made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Make sure you set the offset of memory stream to zero after writing.  The offset is automatically set to end of stream which may give this error.  If you are reading from a file you need to use UTF8 encoding.  So normally I use a binary reader to read from the memory stream an image. or use any stream type the you can set the encoding to UTF8.

Comment: thanks jdweng. How do I I do that? i.e set the offset of memory stream to zero - and use UTF8 encoding?

Comment: I have tried this with a jpg image file, and it works. Do you still think I need to set the offset of memory stream to zero after writing & use UTF8 encoding?

Comment: What is the type of the variable `fcr`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the position before using it.

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fcr.FileContents))
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
}
```

Comment: This was my problem. Could you please point to documentation explaining this?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I don't know if this is documented. I found the issue by downloading the .Net Framework source code and debugging.

Comment: This solved my issue but on a FileStream. I was using CopyToAsync and had to set the source stream position to 0.